# static address with gdb. change without gdb

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I have some difficulty do understand a C code found in a book(The Shellcode's handbook):

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned long find_start(void)
{
        __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}
int main()
{
        printf("%x\n",find_start());
}
```

if i run it with gdb more than one time i have always the same result(the same address):

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
***bffff4a8***
[Inferior 1 (process 5384) exited with code 011]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
***bffff4a8***
[Inferior 1 (process 5387) exited with code 011]
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 
***bffff4a8***
[Inferior 1 (process 5388) exited with code 011]
```

and that's ok for me but when i run it without gdb the result change:

```
root@debian:~# /tmp/a.out 
***bfb5f2b8***
root@debian:~# /tmp/a.out 
***bffa6c58***
```

do you know why? 
(i am on debian 7)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `gdb` disable address space randomization (ASLR).

To see randomization state in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) show disable-randomization
```

To enable it in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization
```

To disable address randomization for your processes:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
```

To disable address randomization for a specific program:

```
setarch `uname -m` -R program [program_arguments]
```